# Replace clause in Sqlalchemy selectable

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I want to replace one clause in an existing SqlAlchemy `Selectable` object. Specifically, I have a query that is supposed to run on a Postgres database that operates on a JSON column:

```
sa.select([t.c.col1]).where(sa.func.json_extract_path_text(t.c.col1, 'name') == 'test'))
```

For testing, I have an in-memory Sqlite database that does not support the `json_extract_path_text` function, so I'd like to replace that `WHERE` clause with a similar function that does string manipulation instead.

Since I cannot change the production query I receive in my testing function, I would like to replace the clause after it has been created. Is there an API to get the syntax tree of a `selectable`?

Comment: This is pretty much the reason why one should test against the same DB product they use in production. Have you considered [mocking the missing function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function) in sqlite instead of replacing the call?

Comment: Thanks! If you put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Ilya's suggestion and implemented my own json_extract_path_text function and used Sqlite's `create_function` to put it in the DB:

```
conn = self.engine.connect()
conn.connection.create_function('json_extract_path_text', -1, json_extract_path_text)
```